# AWS - How to send S3 artifacts from codebuild to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-codebuild

I recently was able to successfully send my artifacts to an S3 bucket using Code Build, but now I want to send those exact artifacts to a specific place in my EC2 instance.

I've been reading the AWS docs non-stop, but I haven't been able to configure Code Deploy in a way that works. Can anyone guide me to a proper source that teaches how to use appspec files and how Code Deploy works?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeDeploy simply fetches your code from S3/GitHub to your EC2 Instances and deploy it using appspec.yml.

Place your appspec.yml file in the root of your code.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html

Create a Deployment group which will contain either your EC2 Instances (Use tags to find the EC2 Instances) or AutoScaling group.

Configure it to use the deployment strategy as per your requirement which is AllAtOnce,HalfAtOnce,OneAtATime and it's done.

( Make sure your EC2 Instances are running CodeDeploy agent )
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install.html

Create a deployment which will get your code from S3 bucket and deploy on EC2 Instances.